# MySQL Databases not Showing

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I just uninstalled and reinstalled mySQL 8.0 in accordance with the instructions provided on their website. I had some previously created databases that I wanted to access so I put the database folders into the Data file like so:

[image: Data File that my.ini points too]

When I load up MySQL Workstation, those databases dont appear:
[image: MySQL Workstation Instance]

I've tried the Edit > Preferences > SQL Editor > Show metadata solution and those databases still wont show up. I was hoping someone more familiar with MySQL knew how to import previously created schema.